# Is AngularJS in .net can be used only in MVC

Tags: .net, angularjs

I think this question is off the leak for Stackoverflow. I want to learn Angular Js but when ever i search it represent that the Angular Js can be only used on MCV pattern. Are we can not use the Angular js in Simple AsP.NET application . Any resource or Link for to come out with this.

Comment: I used angular.js in asp.net as well & in PHP also.

Comment: @Ashish is any simple for asp.net i really thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end its just a JavaScript which can be used in normal webforms as well

It depends on what you are trying to do. NodeJS could also be an option

[Link1](http://mahedee.net/introduction-to-angularjs-and-bootstrap-in-asp-net-web-form/)

[Link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630644.aspx)

It depends on what you are trying to do. NodeJS could also be an option